# How do I fix this json query?

Tags: android, json, getjson, jsonpath, jsonresponse

I am trying to fix my json query, but everytime i copy paste in json parser validator it shows me its incorrect, but it's hard for me to understand what i am missing as I am new to this. Any clue what I am missing?
Here's my query-request:

```
 private final static String QUERY_UPDATE = "\"E\": \"Update\","
            +     "\"W\": '{'"
            +       "\"Pages\": \"{0}\""
            +     "'}'";
```

and corresponding call:

```
 public static String getUpdate(String code) {
        return ComposerUtils.getSimpleQuery(MessageFormat.format(QUERY_UPDATE, new Object[] {
                code
        }));
    }
```

Here's the request as I see being sent:

```
{  "Entity": { "E": "Update","W": {"Pages": "[{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_001","IsSelected":"true"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_058","IsSelected":"true"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_014","IsSelected":"true"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_006","IsSelected":"true"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_036"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_012"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_017"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_039"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_009"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_002"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_003"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_004"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_010"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_008"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_028"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_027"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_378"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_060"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_061"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_062"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_064"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_063"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_032"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_023"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_016"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_015"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_660"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_024"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_021"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_031"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_026"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_025"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_019"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_038"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_053"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_033"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_068"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_069"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_497"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_007"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_022"},{"PageCode":"SP_PAGE_035","IsSelected":"true"}]"}}}
```

Comment: Try pasting the resulting JSON string in jsonlint.com - it gives verbose errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No quotes are required while setting up a JSON array:

"Pages": "[..... ]"

It should just be

"Pages": [ .... ]

Comment: can u show me with respect to  private final static String QUERY_UPDATE = "\"E\": \"Update\","
            +     "\"W\": '{'"
            +       "\"Pages\": \"{0}\""
            +     "'}'";

Comment: Can you please try:

private final static String QUERY_UPDATE = "\"E\": \"Update\","
            +     "\"W\": '{'"
            +       "\"Pages\": {0}"
            +     "'}'";

Comment: glad i could be of help :)